# Make element visible on ajax in JSF2

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have `dataTable` in my page. Initially I want it to be hidden, and show after fetching data by AJAX request. I know how to fetch data and put into table, but I don't know how to show table if it is hidden. Here is the code:

```
<h:commandButton value="aa">
  <f:ajax execute="from to validTo" render="transportOffers"/>
</h:commandButton>
<p:dataTable id="transportOffers" value="${cargoOffer.transportsForCargo}" var="transport">
  <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="${transport.company}"/>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Table is visible initially, even if it is empty. If I set `rendered="false"` it is invisible, and remains invisible also after AJAX request.

How can I make it hidden initially, and to show up after populating with data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try having the dataTable to render conditionally based on the size of the list:

```
rendered = "#{cargoOffer.transportsForCargo.size() != 0}"
```

Comment: That almost works :) Problem is that when it is not rendered initially, ajax response want's to update it, but fails to find it. Solution is to wrap it into something else, and update this something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think if `rendered=false` then the element isn't created, so the AJAX request can't find it.